# Mercurial: How to setup hg-ssh with user/pass?

Tags: ssh, mercurial

I need to give certain outside developers access to create Mercurial repositories on our server. However, I don't necessarily want them to have actual SSH logins to browse the server -- or at the least, I only want to create one SSH account. I like the idea that hg-ssh based solutions involve creating a single login exclusively for Mercurial usage, but I don't really understand the process of setting this up.

I know there's something about creating an authentication key for password-less authentication, but I don't really care about that; I'd just as soon have them enter a password. Regardless, I just need this setup ASAP with minimal server access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use SSH keys if you want to use [`hg-ssh`](http://www.selenic.com/repo/hg/raw-file/stable/contrib/hg-ssh) — the restricted shell is only triggered when you log in with a SSH key. Read the header in `hg-ssh` for instructions on how to set it up:

> To be used in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` with the `command` option, see sshd(8):
>
> ```
> command="hg-ssh path/to/repo1 /path/to/repo2 ~/repo3 ~user/repo4" ssh-dss ...
> ```
>
> (probably together with these other useful options: `no-port-forwarding`, `no-X11-forwarding`, `no-agent-forwarding`)
>
> This allows pull/push over SSH from/to the repositories given as arguments.
>   If all your repositories are subdirectories of a common directory, you can
>   allow shorter paths with:
>
> ```
> command="cd path/to/my/repositories && hg-ssh repo1 subdir/repo2"
> ```
>
> You can use pattern matching of your normal shell, e.g.:
>
> ```
> command="cd repos && hg-ssh user/thomas/* projects/{mercurial,foo}"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`hg-ssh` use a feature of SSH where you can force execution of a command and only this command when a specific SSH key is used.

If you configured a key to execute `/bin/echo "Hello, goodbye" and you start`ssh login@host /bin/ls` , the output will be "Hello, goodbye" and the connection will end.